# Closing MCBrowserViewController disconnects MCSession

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I've done more than three days worth of research to fix my problem and I haven't seen anyone with a solution to my problem. The Browser invites an Advertiser, the Advertiser accepts, and the MCSession changes to a connected state. However, once the MCBrowserViewController is closed (by either the cancel or the done button), the MCSession disconnects. As long as I don't close the MCBrowserViewController, the MCSession stays connected. I don't understand why or how this works and I've even tried debugging the process, but it got too deep into threads for me to understand.

Please tell me it's just something wrong with my code.

```
-(void)setUpMultiPeer{
    self.myPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:pos];

    self.mySession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID];

    self.browserVC = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"svctype" session:self.mySession];

    self.advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"svctype" discoveryInfo:nil session:self.mySession];

    self.browserVC.delegate = self;

    self.mySession.delegate = self;


}

-(void)dismissBrowserVC{
    [self.browserVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)browserViewControllerDidFinish:(MCBrowserViewController *)browserVC{
    [self dismissBrowserVC];
}

-(void)browserViewControllerWasCancelled:(MCBrowserViewController *)browserViewController{
    [self dismissBrowserVC];
}



-(void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state{
    if (state == MCSessionStateConnected) {
        NSLog(@"Connected!");

        //Not entirely sure about this next line...
        self.mySession = session;
    }
    else if (state == MCSessionStateNotConnected){
        NSLog(@"Disconnected");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Somebody Left!"
                                                           message: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [peerID displayName]]
                                                          delegate: nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Got it"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        });
    }
}

//Called by a UIButton
-(IBAction)browseGO:(id)sender {
    [self setUpMultiPeer];
    [self presentViewController:self.browserVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//Called by a UISwitch
-(IBAction)advertiseSwitch:(id)sender {
    if (_advertiseSwitcher.on) {
        [self setUpMultiPeer];
        [self.advertiser start];
    }
    else{
        [self.advertiser stop];
    }
}
```

I have also attempted using a unique MCSession for each the Browser and the Advertiser, but with no success.

Comment: Facing the same thing; keep us posted.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve my problem was start over from ground zero. Waiting on an answer from StackOverflow and from the Apple Developer Forum was taking too long, so I went back to what worked at the very beginning and I will build up from there once more.

[Here](http://techmaster.vn/2013/09/multipeer-connectivity-quick-tutorial/) is a link for an awesome tutorial that I found. I hope this helps someone solve their problem.

However, if anyone sees anything utterly wrong with my code in the question PLEASE DO TELL! I want to know what was causing that bug so that I can learn from my mistakes.

Thank you for stopping by and reading this question.